# Is Schwartz space canonical in any sense?

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

[Schwartz space](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Schwartz_space) $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb C)$ is a dense subspace of $L^2(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb C)$ that appears frequently in physics, because the position operators $X_i$ and momentum operators $P_i$, defined by $(X_if)(x) = x_if(x)$ and $P_if=-i (\partial/\partial x_i)f$ are defined and well behaved on it.

However, there are many other spaces of test functions that could be used (and sometimes are used) in this context, and elsewhere in functional analysis. Still the Schwartz functions seem to appear the most often, so I wonder if they are "natural" or "canonical" in any sense. **Are there any natural characterizations of $\pmb{\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb C)}$?** For example, something like "Schwartz space is the unique subspace of $L^2$ such that ..." or "Schwarz space is the largest subspace of $L^2$ such that ...".

I think I once saw a such a characterization in terms of the position and momentum operators above, along the lines of "the largest subspace such that $X_i$ and $P_i$ are simultaneously defined," or something like that. But I cannot find it now, and I may be misremembering completely.

Comment: Consider the "position" representation spaces in QM merely as the classical paedagogical starting point for the definition of the smallest dual space, that allows Fourier transform and inveerse of the PDE in terms of momentum variables. Position is a ghost in QM that arises in the gauge fields only, aka as the generator of translations in momentum space, eg for scattering, For determining solutions, on needs the Fourier transform of the start data to be time translated by the Fourier transform of the Hamiltonian. Any reasonble Sobolev space adapted to boundary conditions will be convenient.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about a canonical definition of Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, and I in fact asked a similar question on MO

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217663/uniform-definition-of-s-mathbbr-and-s-mathbbq-p

There is however a canonical definition of the dual space $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$
which is Schwartz's original definition of the notion of "spherical distributions".
Use the stereographic projection to see $\mathbb{R}^d$ as the $d$-dimensional sphere $\mathbb{S}^d$ minus the point at infinity.
A distribution on the compact smooth manifold $\mathbb{S}^d$ restricts on the open subset $\mathbb{R}^d\subset\mathbb{S}^d$ to a distribution in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Now one may ask which distributions are obtained in this way and the answer is exactly the temperate distributions, i.e., the elements of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$.
I don't if from this characterization as a set there is a canonical way to obtain the LCTVS topology which makes this into a complete space, i.e., a way to recover the canonical strong dual topology of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$. If this is done, then one can take the strong dual of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and recover Schwartz space at least as an abstract LCTVS.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, I think the main reason $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is natural to use is that it is a space which is densely contained in many interesting function spaces, while at the same time is left invariant by the Fourier transform. If the Fourier transform mapped $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$ to itself, then $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)$ would be used instead of $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, but it is of course not the case.

So it is often much more natural and convenient to use $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ if you work with the Fourier transform. But of course it does not mean that you use it all the time. As you said, different spaces are used depending on the setting and the applications.

---

**Edit 1**: I was wondering if $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the smallest (if not the only…?) space which is a translation and dilation invariant, dense, proper subset of $L^2$ and is left invariant by the Fourier transform… Of course this is not true, one could simply take $\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n)+\mathcal F(\mathcal D(\mathbb R^n))$, but maybe adding some more hypotheses it becomes true.

---

**Edit 2 (the actual answer)**: What about

- “$\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the largest subspace of $L^2$ which is invariant by the Fourier transform and by the operators $\partial_i$”
  This is true almost by definition of $\mathcal S(\mathbb
     R^n)$, and it is a nice characterization. Some equivalent characterizations are
- “$\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the largest subspace of $L^2$ which is invariant by the operators $X_i$, $P_i$”
- “$\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the largest subspace of $L^2$ which is invariant by the Fourier transform and by the operators $X_i$, $P_i$”.

**Rough explanation.** The Schwartz space consists of all functions $f$ such that $X^\alpha P^\beta f\in L^\infty$ for all multiindices $\alpha,\beta$ (rephrasing the mathematical definition with physics notation). It is known (although I don’t remember the details of the proof) that one can equivalently substitute $L^\infty$ with $L^2$, and the two definitions coincide. This way (with some straightforward adjustments) we prove the second characterization. The first and third one are equivalent to the second one essentially because $P_i$ is the coniugation of $X_i$ via the Fourier transform, and viceversa (e.g., $X_i=\mathcal F P_i\mathcal F$ up to reflection and multiplication by constant).

---

**Edit 3**: Another interesting one would be “$\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the largest subspace of $L^2$ of smooth functions which is left invariant by the Fourier transform”, but maybe this one is false.

Comment: I like these answers a lot if they're true, but they aren't so obvious to me. Can you provide a slightly more explicit argument supporting them?

Comment: Also, I have seen the momentum operator $P_i$ defined using the weak derivative, which allows it to operate on non-smooth functions. Do your statements apply to this form of $P_i$, or do they assume we are restricting to smooth function spaces?

Comment: I edited that part giving the main ideas. Is it more clear?

Comment: I am thinking of $P$ as a distributional derivative, or weak derivative if you want. Saying that $Pf$ is in $L^2$ is a concise way of saying that $f$ admits a weak derivative in $L^2$. In any case, it does not matter how we think of it, since in all cases the functions we obtain have to be smooth.

Comment: This helps. But I'm still confused by how (2) implies (1). For example, $C^\infty_0$ is also invariant under $X_i$ and $P_i$, but this doesn't make it invariant under $\mathcal F$. So somehow the maximality is necessary for this implication?

Comment: Proof of (2) implies (1). Clearly, $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfies the properties of $(1)$, so we show the maximality. Assume $f$ is not in $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$. Then, by the (revised) definition of $\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$, there exist multiindices such that $X^\alpha P^\beta f$ is not in $L^2$. But $X^\alpha P^\beta f= \mathcal FP^\alpha\mathcal F P^\beta f$ (up to unimportant factors). So, any space that satisfies the property contained in $(1)$ cannot contain $f$ (since we assume that the space has to be a subset of $L^2$ and invariant under $\mathcal F$ and the operators $P_i$).

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen this remarked in the other answers yet, even though to me it seems the most natural: In QM algebras of operators are whats crucial. If the operators are unbounded one has a problem that the composition of operators is not necessarily well defined. Take the following definition of a representation of a $*$-algebra by possibly unbounded operators:

> **Def.**
> Let $A$ be a $*$-algebra, $H$ a Hilbert space. A representation of $A$ on $H$ is a pair $(D_\rho, \rho)$ where$D_\rho\subseteq H$ is a dense subspace and $\rho: A\to \mathrm{Lin}(D_\rho, H)$ is linear with $\rho(a)(D_\rho)\subseteq D_\rho$ for all $a\in A$ and $\rho(ab)=\rho(a)\rho(b)$ as well as $\rho(a^*)=\rho(a)^*\lvert_{D_\rho}$.

Lets say a representation $(D_\rho, \rho)$ is maximal if there is no representation $(D_{\rho'},\rho')$ with $D_{\rho}\subsetneq D_{\rho'}$ and $\rho'(a)\lvert_{D_\rho}=\rho(a)$.

$\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$ is then the maximal domain of the standard representation of the Heisenberg algebra, being the intersection of the domains $D((1+x^2)^n(i\partial_x)^m)$.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, there are two such properties (in fact, they might be equivalent, but I'm not 100% sure of that)

- The Schwartz space is the "canonical" space for Fourier transform

Fourier Transforms are defined over the space of all integrable functions. However, it is not (in the function-sens) bijective; meaning some functions do not have an inverse Fourier transform. However, like for any operation you can restrict the Fourier Transform to a subspace over which it is a bijection, and the biggest such space is $\mathcal{S}$.

- The dual of $\mathcal{S}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{S}$. (Dual as in the space of linear forms.)

In deed, you can show that when studying integrable functions the dual of the dual is isomorphic to the original space. This is what allows to construct distribution theory (dual of test function space). Some subspaces of integrable functions (like $L_1$ or test functions, or $L_2$) have duals that are either "bigger" or "smaller" than themselves. Schwartz is the biggest space whose dual is basically itself.

Finally (to get back to physics) a great property of Schwarz space is also that you can use Stokes formula to the infinite limit:
$$\int_\Omega \partial f = \int_{\partial \Omega} f = 0$$
And like you mentioned, it is dense in $L_2$. This allows (you can make it rigorous by a lot of painful proofs, or just assume it "physics' style") to extend many properties of Schwartz (especially the previous one) to $L_2$ (the actual physical space) by considering a sequence of functions of $\mathcal{S}$ converging towards something in $L_2$.

So sometimes, in physics, we assume being in Schwarz wile in fact not being in it, simply because, in the limit, it doesn't really matter, so we might as well for shortening the proofs.

Comment: Can you comment a bit about the "dual of Schwartz functions is isomorphic to the space of Schwartz functions" part? Isomorphic as what? Also you seem to say that $L^2$ is not isomorphic to its dual (I am a bit confused by that statement as every Hilbert space is isomorphic to its (topological) dual as a Hilbert space).

Comment: I agree with @SeverinSchraven that, if we are considering $\mathcal S$ as a subspace of $L^2$, the stated characterization already applies to $L^2$, which is isomorphic to its dual (and moreover, the continuous extension of the Fourier transform to $L^2$ is in fact bijective, and even unitary). So I am not sure the first part is correct.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "using Stokes's formula to the infinite limit."

Comment: Consider $\Omega(R)$ to be a ball or radius $R$ in your space (no dimensional constraint). $\int_{\Omega(R)} \partial f = \int_{\partial \Omega(R)} f$ Now, if $f \in \mathcal{S}$ because $f$ decreses faster than any polynomial at infinity (and that the surface of $\partial \Omega(R)$ is polynomial in $R$) you notice that $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\Omega(R)} \partial f = 0$... This is commonly used in physics (we say that "the field $f$ decreases fast at infinity").

Comment: Hence if $\Omega$ is your total space, you can say that $\boxed{\int_\Omega \partial f = 0}$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven sorry but I really can't (I mean not beyond telling you that the dual of a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $E$ is the set of linear function of $E \to \mathbb{K}$). Because, although this is pretty straightforward in finite dimension, it becomes a total mess in infinite dimension. In fact, you start having different non-equivalent meanings of duality. I studied this two years ago (and have a bad memory) and it took a few months to simply write properly.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven If you want to google it on your own, I think the precise notion was "topological dual" although I may be wrong. And the morphisms were highly non-trivial. They were topological morphisms but each with respect to different families of norms...So yeah, my answer was basically about the general "idea" of why $\mathcal{S}$ is canonical, but if you want to have a deeper understanding, I don't know any other way than looking into the rigorous theory of distribution theory.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm truly sorry if you are left with a feeling of unsatisfaction after reading this. (I know I would) and if you choose to start digging into distribution theory, good luck to you  (but you'll see, it's great).

Comment: Now I see what you mean about using Stokes's theorem. However, I don't think this is a characterization of $\mathcal S$. The same is true of $C_0^\infty$, the space of smooth compactly supported functions. I'm looking for a characterization that uniquely determines $\mathcal S$ in a mathematically rigorous sense.

Comment: The topological dual of $\mathscr S$ (with its natural Fréchet space topology) is **not** isomorphic to $\mathscr S$. The dual $\mathscr S'$ is the space of *tempered distributions*.

Comment: @WillG no, indeed, you are correct this is not specific to $\mathcal{S}$. It's just that I've noticed it being used a a justifications sometimes (my QFT teachers like to say their fields are in $\mathcal{S}$ but the Stoke-like property previously mentioned is the only property they truly use). If you want a TRUE justification of canonical, the only thing I see is the self-dual property and the inverse Fourier property that I mentioned previously. Any better idea is out of the scope of my knowledge I'm afraid. Sorry...

Comment: @Jochen isn't any tempered distribution the canonical distribution of a Swartz function? Cause' that's the isomorphy I remembered from my courses...

Comment: What is *the canonical distribution of a Schwartz function*?

Comment: @Jochen well, I'm not sure about the notation (it might just be my teacher's) but consider a function $f$ we call $[f]$ the distribution canonically associated to $f$; with for any $g$ a test function $[f](g):= f*g$. It is in this sens that I talk about morphisms (plus a lot of topology that I forgot). And it seems to me that $\forall f \in \mathcal{S} \quad [f] \in \mathcal{S}^*$ (i.e. $[\mathcal{S}] \simeq \mathcal{S}$. Does this ring a bell? (If not I might simply be confusing with something else... I haven't played with distributions for a while.)